# IndexDB issue in IE10

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer-10, html5-appcache

IndexDB is not working for a website(Production) whereas same code and same script is working for my testwebsite(UAT).

But it is working in Chrome. When I go to setting and localstorage and database I can't see my production url. I see only testing url

Any guess what could be the issue.

Thanks
Vinod

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I add this to the head section if something does not work in IE10 but it does in other browsers.

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=9"/>
```

Comment: <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=Edge"> this solved my issues but your point is valid..thanks a ton